# Como corregir el error de sintaxis, 'if' inesperado (T_IF) en PHP

Tags: php

Como solucionar este error que me lanza al dar clic al botón, ya que apenas actualice a la versión 7.3 de PHP, ya que anteriormente tenia la versión 5.6

El siguiente error esta la sentencia del if anidado:

**Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in **C:\xampp\htdocs\ProyectoHotel\Update.php** on line **13**

Update.php

```
<?php
  include("conexion.php");
  $idHabitacion = (int) $_POST['idHabitacion'] ?? 0;
  $estatus = $_POST['estatus'] ?? '';


 if($idHabitacion > 0 && ($estatus == 'Ocupado' || $estatus == 'Disponible') {

 $consulta = "UPDATE habitaciones SET estatus = '$estatus' WHERE idHabitacion = $idHabitacion"



if($conexion->query($consulta)) {
    echo 'La habitación $idHabitacion ahora tiene estado $estatus';
 } else {
    echo 'Hubo un error al actualizar habitación';
   }
 })  else {
    echo 'No se recibieron correctamente ID de habitación y estatus';
  }
?>
```

Comment: Me lo comentaron en otro foro que tenia que crearlo de esa manera.

Comment: En esta pregunta me lo corrigieron https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/444189/como-puedo-corregir-el-error-de-php-en-el-oprerador-de-fusion-null/444210?noredirect=1#comment792084_444210

Comment: ¿Cuál es la función de parentesis ")" que hay delante del esle?
Ese parentesis es el que te esta dando el error. La estructura es if(condicion){codigo;}else{codigo;}

Comment: Yo lo que noto es que te falta un paréntesis de cierre en tu primer condicional

Comment: El parentesis que le falta debe ser el que esta delante del else dando el error. Ese detalle no lo había visto,

Comment: Si ya vi el error no hay un cierre del mi primer condicional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución es muy sencilla: Tienes un parentesis  `)` que hay entre el cierre del if y else.
Un else siempre tiene que ir precedido por un if y el parentesis no sabe como interpretarlo

```
    if($condicion){
       $a=0;
   }else{
     $a=-1;}
```

Por lo tanto antes de la palabra reservada else sólo puede haber un cierre de llaves `}` o un `;` en caso de que bloque if sea de una sola instrucción
En tu caso tu código debería quedar así

```
<?php
  include("conexion.php");
  $idHabitacion = (int) $_POST['idHabitacion'] ?? 0;
  $estatus = $_POST['estatus'] ?? '';


 if($idHabitacion > 0 && ($estatus == 'Ocupado' || $estatus == 'Disponible')) {

 $consulta = "UPDATE habitaciones SET estatus = '$estatus' WHERE idHabitacion = $idHabitacion";


//condicion interna
if($conexion->query($consulta)) {
    echo 'La habitación $idHabitacion ahora tiene estado $estatus';
 } else {
    echo 'Hubo un error al actualizar habitación';
   }
//fin condicion interna


 }  else {
    echo 'No se recibieron correctamente ID de habitación y estatus';
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

creo que lo que te está faltando es el punto y coma ";" al final de la sentencia:

```
 $consulta = "UPDATE habitaciones SET estatus = '$estatus' WHERE idHabitacion = $idHabitacion"  //<-- falta un punto y coma
```

Comment: si le pongo el ; me salta este error: <br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected ';' in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\ProyectoHotel\Update.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />